# cgi-bin returning internal server error due to compilation failure

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

I moved my script to a new server with almost identical configuration (apache/centos) but the cgi-bin has been failing to work ever since. For past one week I have googled every possible solution and isolated the error by executing script from command line. Output i get is as follows for a simple test file:

```
[root /var/foo/public_html/cgi-bin]# perl -dd /var/foo/public_html/cgi-bin/test.cgi
Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.32
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(/var/foo/public_html/cgi-bin/test.cgi:2):
2:  print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
Unknown error
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/Term/ReadLine/Perl.pm line 63.
at /usr/local/share/perl5/Term/ReadLine/Perl.pm line 63
Term::ReadLine::Perl::new('Term::ReadLine', 'perldb', 'GLOB(0x18ac160)',     'GLOB(0x182ce68)') called at /usr/share/perl5/perl5db.pl line 6073
DB::setterm called at /usr/share/perl5/perl5db.pl line 2237
DB::DB called at /var/foo/public_html/cgi-bin/test.cgi line 2
Attempt to reload Term/ReadLine/readline.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/Term/ReadLine/Perl.pm line 63.
END failed--call queue aborted at /var/foo/public_html/cgi-bin/test.cgi line 63.
at /var/foo/public_html/cgi-bin/test.cgi line 63
[root /var/foo/public_html/cgi-bin]#
```

The code of the test file I am using is:

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/perl
 print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

 print "testing...\n";
```

I have checked the path to perl, perl version etc etc and everything seems to be ok. However the script is not exceuting and gives a 500 internal server error. I am running php5 with dso handler and susEXEC on. susEXEC logs does not say anything except that the cgi script has been called. This problem is completely baffling me and my little experience with cgi/perl is not helping. Can anyone point me in a right direction to solve this?

Comment: Term::ReadLine::Perl is used by the debugger, not your script.

Comment: What happens if you run `ls -l test.cgi` and also `./test.cgi` in the cgi-bin directory?

Comment: @mark I get this output -rwxr-xr-x 1 foouser foouser 82 Jul 22 18:49 test.cgi

Comment: sh: ./test.cgi: Permission denied

Comment: Have you got `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/` and also `Options +ExecCGI` in your Apache config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this eventually, posting it for the sake of posterity:

On moving server I mounted the filesystem on a different partition as the home partition ran out of memory. I forgot to give exec permissions to the new mountpoint, that's why the cgi scripts were not executing.

Answer (score 0):

As someone commented already check the permissions and also try to run the file from the console.

A likely problem is that when you switched servers the path to perl changed and your shebang line is wrong. A common technique to avoid this is to use #!/usr/bin/env perl instead.

When you recieve a 500 error apache should also log something in the error log (your vhost config might define a custom error log instead the default one so check that if you're having trouble finding the error message.

Also there is no reason to run your script under the Perl Debugger, unless your goal is to experiment with the Perl Debugger (and with no variable defined it is pointless as an example). My advice is don't use the Perl Debugger. A lot of experienced Perl programmers, (probably a big majority) never or rarely use it.